# ngTable filter and sorting not working

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, ngtable

I am trying to make a table that I can sort and filter,
I copied the code from the ngTable example's and it's not working. I can't filter and I can't sort.

I searched for a solution, but all the answers I saw are for the older version, they changed how the things works now.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="demoController as demo">
        <h2 class="page-header">Loading data - External array</h2>
        <table ng-table="demo.tableParams" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
            <tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
                <td data-title="'MyProperty'" sortable="'MyProperty'" filter="{MyProperty: 'number'}">{{row.MyProperty}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngTable", "ngResource"]);
(function () {

    app.controller("demoController", demoController);
    demoController.$inject = ["NgTableParams", "$resource"];

    function demoController(NgTableParams, $resource) {

        var Api = $resource('Home/user');
        this.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
            filter: { MyProperty: 1 },
            sorting: { MyProperty: "123" }
        }, {
            getData: function (params) {
                // ajax request to api
                return Api.query(params.url()).$promise.then(function (data) {
                    params.total(data.length); // recal. page nav controls
                    return data;
                });
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

C#:

```
public JsonResult user()
{
    List<Models.Bae> hw = new List<Models.Bae>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        Models.Bae ba = new Models.Bae(i);

        hw.Add(ba);
    }

    return Json(hw, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Angularjs table via sorting and filter on columns example as http://angularjsaz.blogspot.com/2015/09/angularjs-table-via-sorting-and-filter.html  maybe help you.